Winter Bash 2014

As another year draws to a close, we wanted to do something fun and
  lighthearted with our communities, as a way of celebrating the many
  amazing people who make the sites awesome. So, we’re announcing Winter
  Bash 2014!
Most of you probably remember previous years’ events, but I’ll recap
  anyway, for the newbies among us. Winter Bash is an annual event that
  can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users
  earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous
  to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which
  their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats
  in a leaderboard that looks something like this: 

Winter Bash 2014 will again be available to all sites that choose to participate. We’re redesigning all the hats and adding some extra
  features to keep things fresh and exciting. 
Some Details
This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Users
  will be able to see their entire hat collection on
  winterbash2014.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
  hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
  available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
  will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
  the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

The community of every site on the Stack Exchange gets to choose if they would like to take part in this event. Based on the very positive feedback from the last two years (2013, 2012), in which nobody has made any objections to taking part, I would like LEGO Stack Exchange to be involved in this years Winter Bash.
However, if any one has any objections to taking part, please explain why in response to this question. 
Whilst last year the default options was to opt-out of the event, this year we must contact Stack Exchange if we do not wish to be involved.
All responses must be in by 1st December 2014.

Huzzah! More hats :-D

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Winter Bash 2014 happened over a year ago.
